# Extension Autodesk forge: the elements of my model can not be defined

Tags: autodesk-forge, vscode-extensions, autodesk-viewer

I was trying to deploy an extension that was developed using three.js in the IoT-demo-app-extension, but as soon as my extension was loaded, the "add sensor" functionality failed and when I select elements, the sensor figures don't change. What could be the possible causes of this issue?

[image]

These Errors are in console whenever I select any elements of my model.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could it be related to id references? Please check it and let us know.

Comment: @Mojgan, If you have overridden Selection event in your code then Can you check or share the snippet? I think, this problem is related to Selection event function If this event is overridden.